# How to store data to variable in HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-history

I am trying to store a value from a HTTP request into `temperature`. The value will be in the form of characters '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'.

After storing the temperature, I want to do some comparison. For example, if it is `10` I want to draw a full filled rectangle. If it is `5` I want to a draw half filled rectangle. Could you guy give me some advise on how to do this?

I could not store the value to `temperature` and do the comparison.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("DemoCanvas");
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var temperature = parseFloat(this.responseText);
  }
};

if (canvas.getContext) {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  if (temperature = 0) {
    ctx.lineWidth = "3";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
    ctx.strokeRect(5, 50, 350, 200);
    ctx.lineWidth = "3";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.strokeRect(355, 140, 40, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(102, 204, 0)';
    ctx.fillRect(9, 55, 50, 190);
  } else if (temperatue <= 30 || temperature >= 20) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(102, 204, 0)';
    ctx.fillRect(8, 55, 150, 190);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend starting by using proper indentation for your code.

Comment: Also `if (temperature  = 0 )` is an assignment, not a comparison; you're looking for `if (temperature  === 0 )`

Comment: Asynchronous call and you treat it like it is synchronous.

Comment: Where is the AJAX call even invoked?  Honestly, there's *so much* wrong here.  Now might be a good time to scrap this code and start smaller.

Comment: Why have you tagged this css?